# identifier "CvRTrees" is undefined

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using `openCV-3.2.0` and getting an identifier undefined error when initializing the line :

> CvRTrees rtrees;

I think i have added all the necessary header files. So why am i getting this error?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include<conio.h>
    #include <opencv/cv.h>
    #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
    #include <opencv/cvaux.h>
    #include <opencv/ml.h>

    #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
    #include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
    #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
    #include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <string>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <exception>
    #include <array>


    #include "opencv2/ml/ml.hpp"



    using namespace std;
    using namespace cv;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This class exists in OpenCV 2.4.x, However it is not available in newer versions of OpenCV like 3.2.0. Check [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/dd/ded/group__ml.html) the list of all cv::ml classes for OpenCV 3.2.0. I suggest you to use [RTrees](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d8/df1/namespacecv_1_1ml.html) instead. To do this you do not need to include all headers, just include the machine learning module:

```
#include "opencv2/ml/ml.hpp"
```